# Get TFS AreaPath history

Tags: tfs

Someone recently modified area path in our TFS.

Tried to find it with SQL query but could not get any result.

How can i get who did it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried that in TFS 2017 and it still seems that there is no indication who changed the "area path" to a new one. There is some documentation on [Areas and Iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/about-areas-iterations) where recently was commented about the same matter from a Microsoft Representative

> Unfortunately, there is no way to view the change history of Areas or Iterations.